# Does current prefer to take a series path over a parallel path?

Tags: voltage-divider, parallel, series, kirchhoffs-laws, current-divider

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT80f1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Based on the simulation I have done, current here prefers to take the C1 - R2 path first and once C1 is saturated and cuts off it then goes through R3 - R2. Before the C1 saturation, R3 is not used. Does this show that current always prefers to take the series path over parallel if series is available?

Is this true and is there a law on this I can read about?

Comment: Current will start to flow through R3 as soon as there is any voltage across C1.  When C1 is fully charged to 0.5 volts, all current will flow through R3.

Comment: Circuits don't prefer anything, they behave according to the laws of physics.

Comment: What is a "series path" and "parallel path"?

Comment: I believe that everywhere you say "circuit" you meant to say "current".  If this is so, you may wish to _edit your question_ for clarity.  Circuits do not _take_ paths; circuits _are_ the paths.

Comment: @TimWescott done.

Comment: @PeterBennett why does it not go through R3 from the beginning?

Comment: @Dan how much current will flow through R3 when you apply zero volts across it?

Comment: @jsotola but R3 is connected in parallel to the circuit, why is the voltage 0?

Comment: @Dan You need to elaborate on your understanding of what "parallel" and "series" mean, because there's something wrong and I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Hearth https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/uploads/thumbnails/Chapter_5_-_Series_And_Parallel_Circuits.jpg

Comment: @Dan That's correct, but you seem to be misunderstanding something about it...  I'm still confused by what you mean by a "series path" and a "parallel path".

Comment: Before the voltage source is connected, there will be no voltage across R3 or C1.  When the voltage source is connected, current will flow through R2 which will start to charge C1.  As soon as the voltage across C1 rises, the voltage across R3 will also rise, and some current will flow through it, as well as some through C1.

Comment: I'm looking at the wires like water pipes and current being water itself. If I open up the main water valve why does no water pass through R3 initially? why does it all go thought C1?

Comment: @Dan Well, water is a poor analogy. You can get further thinking about compressed air. But even that fails. But with compressed air, you can think of the resistor like a narrow hose with a tiny open nozzle at the end while the capacitor is like an empty air tank (at first.) If you hook things up so that your primary fixed PSI compressed air source (the voltage source here) is connected to both the narrow hose with a nozzle and the empty air tank (using a very wide pipe to connect them) then it's closer. The tank would fill fast at first but eventually would take no more air, at all.

Comment: `why does it all go thought C1?` ... only for an infinitesimally short period of time

Comment: Current 'prefers' the path with less resistance. At the begining the resistance in the capacitor is almost zero, all current goes there until it is filled.  Then there is no other way than R3.

Comment: The hydraulic analogy is, filling up a water tank with a hole in the bottom of it; why does it bother you that water doesn't splash directly into the hole the instant the valve is opened?  Even if it did, a very small amount might dribble out; eventually the tank fills, pressure equalizes, and outflow equals inflow.  Point being, the hole is small so that some head must build before it flows much, or most, of the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Original circuit

The OP's question is conceptual, but this circuit configuration can be seen in many specific applications, e.g. in bias circuits, AC common-emitter amplifiers with emitter degeneration, virtual ground circuits, shunt (Zener diode) stabilizers, etc. Here we can see a voltage divider R1-R2 supplied by a voltage source Vin, and loaded by the capacitor C... or a voltage "stabilizer" R1-C supplied by Vin and loaded by a resistor R2. For concreteness, in the schematic below, I have assumed that enough time has passed so that the capacitor is fully charged to the divider's output voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fptHII.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When unloaded (open circuit), the divider's output voltage is 5 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmYpzv.png)</sup>

## The problem

The OP's question is not so much about how the currents change over time, but rather where they flow. Therefore, the behavior of the capacitor over time is not of interest here; it even makes it difficult to study the circuit because we can not stop the capacitor voltage from changing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fACcR6.png)</sup>

To simulate the circuit operation, we have to apply an input *voltage step*, and then run the *Time-Domain Simulation*.

[image: STEP 3]

The problem is that the simulation is active only during a short time interval; in the rest time, the powerful CircuitLab *Live DC Simulation* is not active (showing the voltages and currents when hovering the mouse over the circuit devices and nodes).

## Emulated capacitor

A powerful idea for exploring this circuit is ***to replace the capacitor with a varying voltage source Vc***. This will free us from the "tyranny of time" and will allow us to explore this AC circuit as a simpler DC circuit through the *Live DC Simulation*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Y0OV.png)</sup>

Then, we can sweep Vc in the CircuitLab *DC Sweep Simulation*, and see how the current through R1 (blue) is distributed between R2 (yellow brown) and Vc (brown). As you can see, time is not involved in obtaining these graphs.

[image: STEP 4]

## Step-by-step exploring

But we would really enjoy exploring the circuit by manually changing Vc step by step slowly and calmly thinking about what is happening in the circuit.

### Visualized resistors

To visualize the currents through resistors without cluttering the experimental setup, we can use another trick thanks to CircuitLab - ***instead of connecting "ideal" (with zero resistance) ammeters in series with the resistors, we can deliberately increase their internal resistance to that of the resistors***. Thus, they will perform the role of both ammeters and resistors (2 in 1).

Similarly, ***instead of connecting "ideal" (with infinite resistance)  voltmeters in parallel to the resistors, we can deliberately decrease their internal resistance to that of the resistors***. Thus, they will perform the role of both voltmeters and resistors.

To distinguish these "worsened" meters from "ideal" ones (like Ic and Vout), I have labeled them as resistors. OK, let's start having fun...

### Experiments

**Vc = 0 V:** First we can zero Vc with which we imitate a fully discharged capacitor. The resistor R2 (R1-R2 voltage divider output) is shorted and all R1's current is diverted to ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5qf51.png)</sup>

**Vc = 2.5 V:** Now two voltage sources are connected in parallel - the one on the left with 5 V (the voltage divider output) and the other on the right with 2.5 V (the "capacitor" Vc).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGQI4F.png)</sup>

So, the current flows from the higher voltage source to the lower voltage source (from left to right).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbRABn.png)</sup>

**Vc = 5 V:** In this extremely interesting situation, we have equalized the "capacitor's" voltage (5 V) with the divider's output voltage (5 V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkpbMi.png)</sup>

As a result, the current between them stops flowing; all the current flows through the voltage divider's resistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGd1su.png)</sup>

The divider "feels" like it is not loaded at all (open circuit) although it is "shorted" by the Ic ammeter and Vc voltage source. The name of this trick is *bootstrapping*; it is used for artificially increasing the resistance of devices.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHwAYr.png)</sup>

**Vc = 10 V:** Let's finally try the situation when Vc is higher than the divider's voltage although it will never happen in the original circuit with a true capacitor (it stops charging when reaching 5 V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRcZxO.png)</sup>

Now the current flows from right to left...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjIfnd.png)</sup>

... and Vc "feels" like it is not loaded at all (open circuit) although it is "shorted" by the R1 ammeter and Vin voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmspjY.png)</sup>

**Vin = 0 V:** It can still happen when Vin = 0. Then the charged capacitor acts as a "power source" and starts discharging through the input source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxmcBU.png)</sup>

## Variations

This "series-parallel" structure (see schematic 4 above) consisting of two voltage sources Vin and Vc) and two resistors (R1 and R2) is worth investigating by successively sweeping each of the four parameters as follows:

**Vin = 0÷10 V**, Vc = 5 V, R1 = 1 kΩ, R2 = 1 kΩ

[image: Variations 1]

Vin = 10 V, **Vc = 0÷5 V**, R1 = 1 kΩ, R2 = 1 kΩ

[image: Variations 2]

Vin = 10 V, Vc = 5 V, **R1 = .1÷1 kΩ**, R2 = 1 kΩ

[image: Variations 3]

Vin = 10 V, Vc = 5 V, R1 = 1 kΩ, **R2 = .1÷1 kΩ**

[image: Variations 4]

## Conclusions

Here are some more considerations that can help answering the OP's question:

- A universal "law of current flow" is that current flows from high to low voltage looking for the path of least resistance.
- When it reaches a junction with different branch resistances, it divides into parts that are inversely proportional to their resistances (*current divider*).
- The question is where the current flows when a voltage source Vc (or charged capacitor) is connected to one of the branches. Then it determines, according to Ohm's law, the current IR2 = Vc/R2 flowing through the resistor R2 in the other branch; the rest (Ic) of the current flows through the voltage source Vc. That is why, the current through the voltage source is significant when the voltage is low.
- In other words, the lower the voltage of the source, the less opposition it offers to current. That is why the current "prefers" to flow through the voltage source when its voltage is low.
- Ic's direction depends on Vc's magnitude: if Vc < VR2 (open circuit, without Vc connected), Ic enters Vc; if Vc > VR2, Ic exits Vc. So, we can find it if we disconnect Vc and measure VR2.

## "Current law"

> ... is there a law on this I can read about?

Let's finally try to formulate the "law" desired by the OP:

**In branch circuits, the current "prefers" to flow (with its greater part) through small resistances and low (opposing) voltages.**

Comment: Way, way more complicated than it needs to be. At the start of the sim, R2/C1 sees a step function, so initially all current goes through C1 and not R3: R3 is essentially shorted out. As the cap charges up, its current decreases while R3 current increases. When the cap is fully charged, all the current will go through R3.

Comment: @hacktastical, My intentions go beyond a simple explanation. I also want to show a way of thinking about and exploring time-dependent circuits through excluding time, visualizing currents through and voltages across resistors, and other techniques. These are implemented very well through CircuitLab's real-time simulation capabilities (the step function does not have this capability). And finally, this approach is beneficial for people like you and me who prefer to complicate things around circuits to enjoy them for a longer time :-)

Comment: @hacktastical, In response to your comment, I have considered the circuit driven by a voltage step and simulated by a *Time-Domain Simulation* (your suggestion). Then I have compared it with my circuit with emulated capacitor driven by an ordinary DC voltage source and simulated by a *Live DC Simulation* and *DC Sweep Simulation*. I think it would be interesting for you to experiment with both simulations to compare them.

Answer (score 2):

Capacitor: at `t=0` is like a closed circuit (short circuit).That is why current is initially flowing through R2-C1 path.

At `'t=infinite'` is like open circuit (no current through the capacitor) so once it is fully charged current is taking R2-R3 path.

Below link is a good reference.

https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/10%3A_Direct-Current_Circuits/10.06%3A_RC_Circuits

Comment: Concise, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *Based on the simulation I have done, current here prefers to take the C1 - R2 path first and once C1 is saturated and cuts off it then goes through R3 - R2. Before the C1 saturation R3 is not used. Is this true and is there a law on this I can read about?*

No, it isn't true except, when \$t = 0\$ and when \$t = \infty\$.

At all points in between the capacitor has a terminal voltage across it and, that terminal voltage must also mean that there is a current flowing through R3.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the current vs time, you’ll see that all the time - with exception of a single time point - the current in fact flows through all elements in the circuit. t=0 is not representative - it’s one point in time out of infinitely many, and it’s those other points that we need to consider too.

The current in fact flows always through the parallel R-C combination. It’s just that it’s apportionment between those two elements that changes over time.

Comment: As if something like "time-dependent current steering" is observed in both branches of the circuit...

Answer (score 0):

No, that is a misanalysis.  At any given point of time, you can consider a capacitor an ideal voltage source.  This results in a voltage across R2, and a voltage across R3.  Ohm's law will tell you then the currents running through R2 and R3, respectively.  If those don't match, there is a current difference flowing into the capacitor, and here "at any given point of time" comes into play since the ideal voltage source a capacitor provides at any given point of time will change its voltage over time when net currents accrue.  The ratio between the capacitor current and its voltage change rate in V/s is its capacitance.

What changes over time is the voltage across the capacitor.  This has nothing to do with "serial" or "parallel" circuits: the circuit remains identical.  Once the voltage across the capacitor has reached a value where the currents across R2 and R3 are identical, no current will divert into the capacitor any more.  That is specific to capacitors, not to series/parallel circuitry.